# How to add new record in LINQ List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have used q Linq query and add new one record at top of index of list

```
List<PMAST> lstPmast = new List<PMAST>();

lstPmast.Add(new PMAST() { EmpId = 0, PCODE = "--Select--", PNAME = "--Select--" });

var GetEmployeeLst = (from d in db.PMASTs
                      where d.CNO == iCNO && d.Isdeleted != true
                      select new
                              {
                                  EmpId = d.EmpId,
                                  PCODE = d.PCODE,
                                  PNAME = d.PNAME
                              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in multiple ways, one of them is just use `AddRange` method of `List`:

```
    List<PMAST> lstPmast = new List<PMAST>();

    lstPmast.Add(new PMAST() { EmpId = 0, PCODE = "--Select--", PNAME = "--Select--" });

    var GetEmployeeLst = (from d in db.PMASTs
         where d.CNO == iCNO && d.Isdeleted != true
         select new
         {
            EmpId = d.EmpId,
            PCODE = d.PCODE,
            PNAME = d.PNAME

    }).ToList();
    lstPmast.AddRange(GetEmployeeLst);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is tagged with ASP.NET MVC, I assume that you are trying to add some default value to a drop down. If this is the case you could directly use the appropriate [`DropDownListFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561(v=vs.118).aspx) helper which allows you to achieve that without the need of inserting such fake records in your view model:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedEmployee, Model.Employees, "--Select--")
```

You no longer need to alter your data model to achieve such purely UI stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of Add:

```
lstPmast.Insert(0,new PMAST() { EmpId = 0, PCODE = "--Select--", PNAME = "--Select--" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add ne record by list.add like :

lstPmast.add(newlistitem);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your list of objects will end up in either an asp.net combobox or a winform combobox.

Here is my suggestion

```
List<Tuple<int,string>> lstPmast;

var lstPmast = db.PMASTs.Where(d => d.CNO == iCNO && !d.Isdeleted).Select(d => Tuple.Create(d.EmpId, e.PCODE + "-" + e.PNAME)).ToList();

// then add a default as the first item in the list
lstPmast.Insert(0, Tuple.Create(0, "--- Select ---"));

// bind the list to your combobox here. Use Item1 as value and Item2 as the description
```